# Verify es module is tree shakable

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I'm authoring a library that outputs ESM / CJS and UMD. I want to test if the es module version is working as expected in an app with tree-shaking, however, I can't figure out a better way other than manually running a build in my test app and look at the file sizes.

I want to know if there is something like https://bundlephobia.com/ but to run against a local module.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/rich-harris/agadoo.

(Some additional garbage text to satisfy StackOverflow's idiosyncracies; ignore.)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation and library! I just tried it but it seems like if I import any external dependencies it marks it as not tree shakeable. Is there a way I can work around this?

Comment: Not currently. It could probably be smarter about figuring that out by itself, or letting you specify `--external` modules or something